# How do I change one page of my WordPress website without changing the theme?

Tags: wordpress

I literally have no background in coding or html. I've been trying to figure out how to make the resume page of my website into two columns without changing the theme of the entire website. Could anyone help me or refer me to a tutorial? I need a thorough step-by-step tutorial because I am totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

You could give WP Easy Columns plugin a try: http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-columns/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a page template. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates for examples and instructions.

And see the rest of the Codex for any of the docs you need to learn WordPress.

Edit theme files with FTP and keep copies of the originals in case you make a mistake and the site whitescreens. See [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and [FTP Clients « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients).

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin and log in. Under the "Pages" tab, you can open up a page and see what template it is using on the right side.

Next, navigate to "Appearance" -> "Editor". On the right side, you will have multiple page templates, for example `page.php`. Find the one that matches the page you are using, open it up and edit away. Pay attention to the PHP syntax and check out the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) for information on the function calls you see within it.

Alternatively, you can find the file, starting at your site root in `/wp-content/themes/yourTheme/`

You can approach the columns issue two different ways, depending how ambitious you are feeling. The easiest way for you would be simply adding two floated divs in your page editor (text mode). Something like this:

```
<div class="page-col">
  <!--content here-->
</div>
<div class="page-col">
  <!--content here-->
</div>
```

Add the following lines to your /wp-content/themes/yourTheme/style.css :

```
.page-col {
  width: 50%; /*may have to be adjusted for padding/margins*/
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```